# Where should my database be stored in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using the [`path_provider`](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) package and I'm wondering what directory I should use for putting my Hive database.

I need it to be cross-platform (at least Android & iOS). I was looking at [`getLibraryDirectory`](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getLibraryDirectory.html) but that doesn't support Android. Would [`getApplicationDocumentsDirectory`](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationDocumentsDirectory.html) be of any use? Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following for your use case:

```dart
final directory = Platform.isIOS ? await getLibraryDirectory() : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

This will provide the best directory for both *iOS and Android*, assuming that you want to store database files that should not be visible to the user.

Comment: Can you explain why `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` isn't the best for iOS?

Comment: @Benjamin It seems that `getLibraryDirectory` is made to store data like this on iOS. From the docs: "where application can store files that are **persistent, backed up, and not visible to the user**, such as sqlite.db." However, I cannot guarantee that it is actually better - I mostly wanted to introduce `Platform.isIOS` as an option.